# How can I draw a rectangular outline (not filled) with PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a solid black rectangle with only the middle part(have an accurate position for the hollow place) being fully transparent. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect). The last parameter of `pygame.draw.rect` is the thickness of line the outline. If the parameter is 0 (or default), then the rectangle is filled, else a rectangle with the specified line thickness is drawn. e.g:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, (x, y, w, h), outlineThickness)
```

[image]

the corners of the rectangle are jagged. However, the corner radius can be set (`border_radius`) to get a better result:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, (x, y, w, h), outlineThickness, border_radius=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer for a terribly worded question. Kudos.