# Missing Corner on Rectangle Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When working on my game, I noticed that shapes have "missing corners." I have tested this with lines and a rectangle. How do I fix this?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PASCOLOR = (199, 121, 121)

# add font
gameFont = pygame.font.Font('PressStart2P.ttf', 25)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 650))
pygame.display.set_caption('test game')

exitgame = False

while not exitgame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitgame = True
    
    gameDisplay.fill(BLACK)
    # add outside rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, WHITE, (100, 100, 1000, 450), 5)

    # Add images
    addimg = pygame.image.load('addimg.png')
    # resize ranta
    addimg = pygame.transform.scale(addimg, (63.5, 87))

    def loadImages():
        gameDisplay.blit(addimg, (110,110))
    loadImages()
    
    # add text to screen
    titletxt = gameFont.render("test game", True, PASCOLOR)
    gameDisplay.blit(titletxt, (400, 40))
        
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Is this how Pygame renders rectangles or an error?
[image: black square with white rectangle]

See that the pixels on the corners are missing.

Comment: you need to show more details. what errors? is it a visual bug? can you share screenshots?

Comment: @drum added image

Answer (score 1):

Set the corner radius (`border_radius`) to get a better result (see [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)):

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, WHITE, (100, 100, 1000, 450), 5)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, WHITE, (100, 100, 1000, 450), 5, border_radius=1)
```

See also [How can I draw a rectangular outline (not filled) with PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854803/how-can-i-draw-a-hollow-rectangle-using-pygame/60855000#60855000).

Comment: Is there any way else to fix it? Because it doesn't seem to work on older versions of Pygame

Comment: @OverUnderAnimations Why do you use an old version!? Pygame 2.0 was released 2 years ago. Anyway, see [How to Make a Border in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095839/how-to-make-a-border-in-pygame/63099536#63099536).

Comment: i'm on a school computer haha